# Bootstrap column floating on right side insteaf of left why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Let's go to exaplain my problem:

I have this `html` code:

```
<div id="nodeInitInsertion" class="row removePadd_oddEven_childs"></div>
```

This is like the parent node where the dynamic content is going to be inserted after an ajax petition. This GET petitions gives us information about what fields should we show in the form *(name, lastname, gender, date of birth, and then extra fields)*

Here for example we have received all of these *(inside there are the inputs but this is the main information you need)*

```
<div id="nodeInitInsertion" class="row removePadd_oddEven_childs">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 relative margin-20-t sex_container"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 relative margin-10-t dateofbirth_container"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 element-children margin-10-t"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 element-children margin-10-t"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 element-children margin-10-t"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 relative margin-10-t nationality_container"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 element-children margin-10-t"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 email_container margin-10-t"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 element-children margin-10-t"></div>
</div>
```

It works all fine the most of the times **(fig. 1)**.

[image]

But when there are 9 "div childrens" or more, the design breaks because one of the `div.col-xs-12` should be in the left and it is in the right. **(fig. 2)**
[image]

And the strange this is that: If I remove a `div.col-xs-12` element before the one is "wrong placed" it goes all OK.

And the most strange this that the element has nothing weird... They have all the same height too.
[image]

Did it happen to you anytime? Like: a column of bootstrap that is totally floating left, is floating to the right? why it happens?

Thank you..

Comment: what are the properties of relative class on "nationality container"

Comment: @AyushSharma they are just classes to do some stuff in JS.. I already fixed it forcing the same height to each element (strange because they had the same..) but doing it in the html works.